# Can inequalities over $n>2$ variables ever imply an inequality over $2$ variables?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Say we have $n$ variables $x_1,x_2...,x_n$.

### **Question 1.**

We want to put conditions of the following form:

$$x_i+...+x_j>x_k+...+x_l$$
Where

1. The left side contains as many variables as the right side (but variables may be used multiple times, e.g.: $2\cdot x_3>x_2+x_1$), and
2. No single inequality is enough by itself to imply an inequality of the form $x_i>x_j$, i.e. with less than $3$ variables (this rules out, for instance, $x_1+x_2+x_3>x_1+x_2+x_4$).

We can have as many such inequalities as we want.

**Is it possible for some $i,k$ to write down a set of such conditions such that all valuations that satisfy them also satisfy $x_i>x_k$?**

---

### Question 2.

What if we restrict to inequalities with certain coefficients? I.e. is it possible if we allow conditions of the form:

$$\alpha^1\cdot x_i+...+\alpha^{n}\cdot x_j>\alpha^1\cdot x_k+...+\alpha^n\cdot x_l$$

Where $\alpha\in (0,1)$, and $n$ is the number of variables in the inequality.

**Is it possible in this case to induce $x_i>x_k$?**

Comment: You need another restriction: that no variable appears on both sides of an equation. Otherwise you could have $x_1+x_2>x_1+x_3$, forcing $x_2>x_3$.

Comment: @TonyK, thanks, edited.

Comment: The way you put it is guaranteed to have readers scratching their heads...

Comment: ...but I suppose it does also rule out other undesirable equations, like $2x_1>2x_2$.

Comment: @TonyK, is this better?

Comment: Now you are letting through inequalities of the form $x_1+x_2+x_3>x_1+x_2+x_4$. I have edited your question to state more precisely what I think is your intention; please let me know if I have misunderstood.

Comment: @TonyK, yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't something like $x_1+x_2>x_3+x_4$ and $x_3+x_4>x_2+x_5$ achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: yes it does, I've asked a followup question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986811/when-does-a-set-of-inequalities-over-series-imply-an-inequality-over-variables